# Book downloader analogue of youtube-dl?

Tags: gratis, open-source, download-manager, ebooks, books

Is there a sort of [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) for downloading books (like Google Books previews, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open source project hosted by CodePlex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=googlebookdownloader), that lets you download Google Books for free by using the Google Books Downloader which is available for free.

> Google Books Downloader Lite is a free, open-source utility that lets
>   out download any book that's available in "full view" from Google
>   Books. Of course, most of these books also feature download links
>   right on the web page, but Google Books Downloader lets you queue up
>   multiple jobs and convert all of the downloaded books to PNG files.

Simply paste the URL of the Google Book you wish to download and clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the currently working commandline (like youtube-dl) tool called [GoBooDo](https://github.com/vaibhavk97/GoBooDo).